# Вопрос по suppressed exceptions в рамках конструкции try-with-resources

Tags: java, исключения

Вот цитата из книги Oracle-Certified-Professiona-Java-SE-8-Programmer-Exam-1Z0-809

> In a try-with-resources statement, there might be more than one exception that could get thrown; for
>   example, one within the try block, one within the catch block, and another one within the finally block.
>   However, only one exception can be caught, so the other exception(s) will be listed as suppressed
>   exceptions. From a given exception object, you can use the method getSuppressed() to get the list of
>   suppressed exceptions.

Попробовал на практике:

```
System.out.println("Type an integer in the console: ");
        try(Scanner consoleScanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("You typed the integer value: " + consoleScanner.nextInt());
            int kil = 8/0;
        } catch(Exception e) {
// catch all other exceptions here ...
            System.out.println("Error: Encountered an exception and could not read an integer from the console... ");
            System.out.println("Exiting the program - restart and try the program again!");
        }finally {
            int kil = 8/0;
        }
```

Результат ничуть не удивил:

```
Type an integer in the console: 
5
You typed the integer value: 5
Error: Encountered an exception and could not read an integer from the console... 
Exiting the program - restart and try the program again!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at package3.MethodReference.main(MethodReference.java:183)
```

Никакого suppress не происходит. Или происходит? Тогда как понимать вывод исключения на консоль? Или я что то неправильно понял?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В твоём коде нет нужды в подавлении. Ты ловишь исключение, логируешь, в этот момент оно считается обработанным, потом управление передается в finally и там выбрасывается новое исключение.

Убери секцию catch  и лови на уровне выше. В этом случае в секции finally будет выброшено новое исключение, при этом в стэке уже  будет одно необработанное - вот в этот момент и произойдет подавление.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        try {
            try (MyResource r = new MyResource()) {
                throw new Exception("from block");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     public static class MyResource implements AutoCloseable {
         public void close() {
             throw new IllegalStateException("from close");
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: catch взял в комменты, снова запустил, снова в консоли исключение, дополнительно взял в коммент выражение в finally. Исключение по любому на консоли выводит. Что я сделал не так? Допущение: вероятно неправильно понял что вы имели ввиду говоря "лови на уровне выше"

Comment: А на уровне выше ловишь? Дефолтный перехватчик подавленные не печатает

Comment: Пожалуйста уточните, что вы имеете ввиду говоря "уровень выше". А "Дефолтный перехватчик подавленные не печатает" интуитивно и так ясно, поэтому смысл написания этой части в цитате - не ясен.

Comment: Короче, почитал повнимательнее. Suppressed автоматически добавляются в исключение только для исключений, которые произошли в момент закрытия ресурсов. В остальных случаях их надо самому добавлять `ex.addSuppressed`

Comment: Добавил в ответ минимальный пример, как увидеть эти "автоматические" suppressed исключения.

Comment: Спасибо.  Ваш ответ достаточно помог.